# Ford E250 slams into 2nd gear when hot

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, e250

This is a 2000 Ford E250.

The transmission slams into second gear when hot.

I pulled the valve body, and the accumulator seals and piston appear to be good. The 1-2 valve also seems fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Get the valve body, seals and piston checked by an autobox specialist, in fact the whole box...

Comment: Unless you have a good set of test gauges it will be difficult to diagnose yourself.  However, if you know enough to pull the accumulator you might want to make the investment.  I don't know which ports to check, but you need to consider mains and "throttle" pressures, along with the accumulator and 1-2 shift valve - you can't visually tell if it's sticking.  The fact that it happens when *hot* points to a seal problem...  I would have replaced the accumulator piston/seals when I had it out - cheap enough.  How dirty was the fluid?  mileage?  Debris messing with a check ball?

Comment: Still apart.  I'll probably throw a new accumulator and spring in as well.  Ordered another valve body too, should cover the bases. Thanks guys.

Comment: Couldn't get the accumulator piston but put new valve body and all seems well so far.